How to increase/decrease Bar sizes in bar chart in Kibana
Im looking for bar chart customization in Kibana;
Right now the bars are too close and get auto adjust. while I want to make them thinner and add spaces between the bars.
Anyone please guide.
I tried doing it in the Lens Editor but couldn't find any option to increase decrease bar spaces.

Can you provide your code and show the output and expected results?

Well, I am new to kibana, so I was utilizing Lens Editor to make visuals. While, I came to knew that there are other ways to do it.
I'm trying Kibana Canvas, hoping this may solve the issue.
Thanks for the reply
